# ECSlidingViewController bound using Xamarin causes crash

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using a binding project to wrap ECSlidingViewController for use with MonoTouch/Xamarin. I have this setup. However when I attempt to open the menu (by triggering a segue on button click) the app crashes with no error report, nor anything in the application output. All I have to go on is the following crash report I retrieved from the console. Can anyone shed any light on the problem?

The only code being executed is:

```
// in ViewDidLoad()
menuButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => ToggleMenu();

private void ToggleMenu()
{
    PerformSegue("ReturnToMenu", this);
}
```

The mammoth crash report. I've removed the irrelevant sections and the 20-odd other threads it ilsted.

```
Process:         TrendsyiOS [20438] Path:           
/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone
Simulator/*/TrendsyiOS.app/TrendsyiOS Identifier:      TrendsyiOS
Version:         0 Code Type:       X86 (Native) Parent Process: 
launchd_sim [20410] Responsible:     launchd_sim [20410] User ID:     
501

Date/Time:       2014-03-07 18:38:48.964 +0000 OS Version:      Mac OS
X 10.9.2 (13C64) Report Version:  11 Anonymous UUID: 
16AD87BD-E1A0-85E1-ABA2-1B42ED40C5AA

Sleep/Wake UUID: BD75E8D8-A7D6-4ADA-8D92-7D304EF39EAC

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information: iPhone Simulator 463.9.4.2, iPhone
OS 7.0.3 (iPhone Retina (4-inch)/11B508)  

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0  
CoreFoundation                  0x0511db71 CFRetain + 113 1   ???      
    0x1426c448 0 + 338084936 2   ???                          
    0x1426c168 0 + 338084200 3   ???                          
    0x1426c3a6 0 + 338084774 4   TrendsyiOS                   
    0x00223a74 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 820 (mini.c:6622) 5   TrendsyiOS
    0x002be66f mono_runtime_invoke + 127 (object.c:2827) 6   TrendsyiOS  
    0x00361b3a get_delegate_for_block_parameter + 138
(monotouch-glue.m:292) 7   TrendsyiOS                       0x00368ee7
monotouch_trampoline + 1847
(.monotouch-trampoline-setup-callstack.inc:70) 8   TrendsyiOS         
    0x0013ace7 -[ECSlidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:] +
49 (ECSlidingViewController.m:413) 9   TrendsyiOS                   
    0x00138f66 -[ECSlidingSegue perform] + 264 (ECSlidingSegue.m:51) 10 
UIKit                           0x03a57203
-[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 554 11  UIKit                            0x034ce280 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] +
72 12  ???                              0x132d61c4 0 + 321741252 13  ???
    0x132d60ec 0 + 321741036 14  ???                          
    0x132a8e79 0 + 321556089 15  ???                          
    0x132b9fe8 0 + 321626088 16  ???                          
    0x12da1c87 0 + 316284039 17  ???                          
    0x10067b6d 0 + 268860269 18  TrendsyiOS                   
    0x00223a74 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 820 (mini.c:6622) 19  TrendsyiOS
    0x002be66f mono_runtime_invoke + 127 (object.c:2827) 20  TrendsyiOS  
    0x0036980a monotouch_trampoline + 4186
(.monotouch-trampoline-invoke.inc:1) 21  libobjc.A.dylib              
    0x04f6e874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77 22
UIKit                           0x033ba0c2 -[UIApplication
sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108 23  UIKit                        
    0x033ba04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
+ 61 24  UIKit                          0x034b20c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66 25  UIKit                        
    0x034b2484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577 26 
UIKit                           0x034b1733 -[UIControl
touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641 27  UIKit                        
    0x033f751d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852 28  UIKit         
    0x033f8184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232 29  UIKit                   
    0x033cbe86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242 30  UIKit               
    0x033b618f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421 31  CoreFoundation 
    0x0512b83f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
+ 15 32  CoreFoundation                 0x0512b1cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235 33  CoreFoundation                   0x0514829e __CFRunLoopRun + 910 34  CoreFoundation               
    0x05147ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467 35  CoreFoundation             
    0x051478db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 36  GraphicsServices             
    0x066b59e2 GSEventRunModal + 192 37  GraphicsServices             
    0x066b5809 GSEventRun + 104 38  UIKit                        
    0x033b8d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225 39  ???                          
    0x110efaa8 0 + 286194344 40  ???                          
    0x110edc1c 0 + 286186524 41  ???                          
    0x110ed7f8 0 + 286185464 42  ???                          
    0x110ed937 0 + 286185783 43  TrendsyiOS                   
    0x00223a74 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 820 (mini.c:6622) 44  TrendsyiOS
    0x002be66f mono_runtime_invoke + 127 (object.c:2827) 45  TrendsyiOS  
    0x002c3eb7 mono_runtime_exec_main + 391 (object.c:4050) 46 
TrendsyiOS                      0x002c3c84 mono_runtime_run_main + 628
(object.c:3678) 47  TrendsyiOS                      0x0018d94d
mono_jit_exec + 93 (driver.g.c:1009) 48  TrendsyiOS                   
    0x0035bdd4 main + 2788 (main.m:489) 49  libdyld.dylib                
    0x056e3701 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0  
libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0590b992 kevent64 + 10 1  
libdispatch.dylib               0x05442f3e _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238 2
libdispatch.dylib               0x05442c7a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 60

Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0590aa26 __recvfrom +
10 1   libsystem_sim_c.dylib            0x0550ca9d recv + 54 2  
TrendsyiOS                      0x0035dfcd recv_uninterrupted + 77
(debug.m:321) 3   TrendsyiOS                        0x0035e1fb
monotouch_process_connection + 187 (debug.m:738) 4   TrendsyiOS       
    0x0035ddd7 monotouch_connect_wifi + 2983 (debug.m:515) 5   TrendsyiOS
    0x0035ce9c monotouch_configure_debugging + 2124 (debug.m:269) 6  
TrendsyiOS                      0x0035a8da -[CocoaThreadInitializer
entryPoint:] + 122 (shared.m:127) 7   Foundation                   
    0x01cbd597 -[NSThread main] + 76 8   Foundation                   
    0x01cbd4f6 __NSThread__main__ + 1275 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib     
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x05905fb6
semaphore_wait_trap + 10 1   TrendsyiOS                     0x00335c6a
mono_sem_wait + 26 (mono-semaphore.c:121) 2   TrendsyiOS              
    0x002668c7 finalizer_thread + 103 (gc.c:1078) 3   TrendsyiOS         
    0x002f60a8 start_wrapper + 376 (threads.c:609) 4   TrendsyiOS        
    0x0032a2c7 thread_start_routine + 151 (wthreads.c:294) 5   TrendsyiOS
    0x00336321 inner_start_thread + 65 (mono-threads-posix.c:49) 6  
TrendsyiOS                      0x00357b0d GC_start_routine + 93
(pthread_support.c:1502) 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x058c45fb
_pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0590aa26 __recvfrom +
10 1   libsystem_sim_c.dylib            0x0550ca9d recv + 54 2  
TrendsyiOS                      0x0035dfcd recv_uninterrupted + 77
(debug.m:321) 3   TrendsyiOS                        0x0035e0c4 sdb_recv +
52 (debug.m:337) 4   TrendsyiOS                     0x001786eb
debugger_thread + 22427 (debugger-agent.c:1475) 5   TrendsyiOS        
    0x0032a2c7 thread_start_routine + 151 (wthreads.c:294) 6   TrendsyiOS
    0x00336321 inner_start_thread + 65 (mono-threads-posix.c:49) 7  
TrendsyiOS                      0x00357b0d GC_start_routine + 93
(pthread_support.c:1502) 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x058c45fb
_pthread_body + 144 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0590ab76
__semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_sim_c.dylib             0x0550c98b nanosleep + 219 2   libsystem_sim_c.dylib            0x0550c836 usleep +
60 3   TrendsyiOS                       0x003628ad monotouch_pump_gc +
61 (monotouch-glue.m:595) 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 
    0x05905f7a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590516c mach_msg + 68 2   CoreFoundation               
    0x05142e49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169 3   CoreFoundation       
    0x051483b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1185 4   CoreFoundation               
    0x05147ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467 5   CoreFoundation             
    0x051478db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6   Foundation                   
    0x01c619de +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 381 7  
Foundation                      0x01cbd597 -[NSThread main] + 76 8  
Foundation                      0x01cbd4f6 __NSThread__main__ + 1275 9 
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 10 
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 11 
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 7:: com.apple.CFSocket.private 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib      
    0x0590aace __select + 10 1   CoreFoundation               
    0x051863eb __CFSocketManager + 875 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0590b046
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c5dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x058c9cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 9:: WebThread 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x05905f7a
mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0590516c
mach_msg + 68 2   CoreFoundation                    0x05142e49
__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169 3   CoreFoundation                 0x051483b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1185 4   CoreFoundation               
    0x05147ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467 5   CoreFoundation             
    0x051478db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6   WebCore                      
    0x0a532f00 RunWebThread(void*) + 608 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib     
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 10: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x05905f7a mach_msg_trap
+ 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0590516c mach_msg + 68 2   CoreFoundation                 0x05142e49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +
169 3   CoreFoundation                  0x051483b1 __CFRunLoopRun +
1185 4   CoreFoundation                 0x05147ac3
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467 5   CoreFoundation               
    0x051478db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6   libAVFAudio.dylib            
    0x05f8d403 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 189 7  
libAVFAudio.dylib               0x05f81882 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*)
+ 114 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0590ab76
__semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_sim_c.dylib             0x0550c98b nanosleep + 219 2   TrendsyiOS                       0x0032ab4a SleepEx
+ 234 (wthreads.c:842) 3   TrendsyiOS                       0x002f4e64 monitor_thread + 164 (threadpool.c:779) 4   TrendsyiOS                
    0x002f60a8 start_wrapper + 376 (threads.c:609) 5   TrendsyiOS        
    0x0032a2c7 thread_start_routine + 151 (wthreads.c:294) 6   TrendsyiOS
    0x00336321 inner_start_thread + 65 (mono-threads-posix.c:49) 7  
TrendsyiOS                      0x00357b0d GC_start_routine + 93
(pthread_support.c:1502) 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x058c45fb
_pthread_body + 144 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 12: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x05905fce
semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10 1   TrendsyiOS                   
    0x00335c12 mono_sem_timedwait + 210 (mono-semaphore.c:82) 2  
TrendsyiOS                      0x002f2c58 async_invoke_thread + 1656
(threadpool.c:1565) 3   TrendsyiOS                      0x002f60a8
start_wrapper + 376 (threads.c:609) 4   TrendsyiOS                   
    0x0032a2c7 thread_start_routine + 151 (wthreads.c:294) 5   TrendsyiOS
    0x00336321 inner_start_thread + 65 (mono-threads-posix.c:49) 6  
TrendsyiOS                      0x00357b0d GC_start_routine + 93
(pthread_support.c:1502) 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x058c45fb
_pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0590aace __select + 10
1   TrendsyiOS                      0x003348e1 mono_poll + 401
(mono-poll.c:76) 2   TrendsyiOS                     0x002f5313
tp_poll_wait + 291 (tpool-poll.c:186) 3   TrendsyiOS                  
    0x002f60a8 start_wrapper + 376 (threads.c:609) 4   TrendsyiOS        
    0x0032a2c7 thread_start_routine + 151 (wthreads.c:294) 5   TrendsyiOS
    0x00336321 inner_start_thread + 65 (mono-threads-posix.c:49) 6  
TrendsyiOS                      0x00357b0d GC_start_routine + 93
(pthread_support.c:1502) 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x058c45fb
_pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 14: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x05905fce
semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10 1   TrendsyiOS                   
    0x00335c12 mono_sem_timedwait + 210 (mono-semaphore.c:82) 2  
TrendsyiOS                      0x002f2c58 async_invoke_thread + 1656
(threadpool.c:1565) 3   TrendsyiOS                      0x002f60a8
start_wrapper + 376 (threads.c:609) 4   TrendsyiOS                   
    0x0032a2c7 thread_start_routine + 151 (wthreads.c:294) 5   TrendsyiOS
    0x00336321 inner_start_thread + 65 (mono-threads-posix.c:49) 6  
TrendsyiOS                      0x00357b0d GC_start_routine + 93
(pthread_support.c:1502) 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x058c45fb
_pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 15:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib      
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x043f5811 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 305 4  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 5   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 16:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x045238f3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 147 4   JavaScriptCore
    0x04523988 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadStartFunc(void*) + 72 5  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 17:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x045238f3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 147 4   JavaScriptCore
    0x04523988 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadStartFunc(void*) + 72 5  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 18:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x045238f3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 147 4   JavaScriptCore
    0x04523988 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadStartFunc(void*) + 72 5  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 19:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x045238f3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 147 4   JavaScriptCore
    0x04523988 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadStartFunc(void*) + 72 5  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 20:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x045238f3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 147 4   JavaScriptCore
    0x04523988 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadStartFunc(void*) + 72 5  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 21:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x045238f3 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 147 4   JavaScriptCore
    0x04523988 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadStartFunc(void*) + 72 5  
JavaScriptCore                  0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*)
+ 76 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 22:: WebCore: CFNetwork Loader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib      
    0x05905f7a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590516c mach_msg + 68 2   CoreFoundation               
    0x05142e49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169 3   CoreFoundation       
    0x051483b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1185 4   CoreFoundation               
    0x05147ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467 5   CoreFoundation             
    0x051478db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 6   WebCore                      
    0x0a075a78 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 360 7   JavaScriptCore  
    0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76 8   JavaScriptCore      
    0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 9  
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 10 
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 11 
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 23: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0590b046
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c5dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x058c9cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 24:: WebCore: LocalStorage 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
    0x0590a7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c6d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
    0x058c8bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71 3   JavaScriptCore        
    0x0473f483 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 67
4   WebCore                         0x0a34d508
WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> >
WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()>
>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void
()>*), double) + 120 5   WebCore                        0x0a34cb06
WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 214 6   JavaScriptCore   
    0x0473df2c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76 7   JavaScriptCore      
    0x0473e425 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21 8  
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c45fb _pthread_body + 144 9  
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c4485 _pthread_start + 130 10 
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c9cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 25: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0590b046
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x058c5dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x058c9cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):   eax: 0x00000000 
ebx: 0x00000000  ecx: 0x0511db00  edx: 0x00000000   edi: 0x0511db0e 
esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xbff18ca8  esp: 0xbff18c90    ss: 0x00000023 
efl: 0x00000246  eip: 0x0511db71   cs: 0x0000001b    ds: 0x00000023  
es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f   cr2: 0x7bc9e000   
Logical CPU:     2 Error Code:      0x00000000 Trap Number:     3

** LOTS OF CRAP**

External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 95275
    thread_create: 2
    thread_set_state: 655

VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=219.1M
resident=94.0M(43%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=125.1M(57%) Writable
regions: Total=182.3M written=27.3M(15%) resident=56.4M(31%)
swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=125.8M(69%)   REGION TYPE              
VIRTUAL
===========                      ======= CG image                             12K CG raster data                     1336K CoreAnimation            
11.3M CoreServices                        424K CoreUI image data                   320K Image IO                           4440K JS JIT generated code   
32.0M JS VM register file                4096K JS garbage collector               2880K Kernel Alloc Once                     4K MALLOC                 
87.6M MALLOC (admin)                       48K SQLite page cache                   896K Stack                              76.5M VM_ALLOCATE             
8268K VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)               96K        reserved VM
address space (unallocated) WebCore purgeable data              468K
WebKit Malloc                      6408K
__DATA                             14.6M
__LINKEDIT                         51.7M
__PAGEZERO                            4K
__TEXT                            167.5M
__UNICODE                           544K mapped file                       337.8M shared memory                         4K
===========                      ======= TOTAL                             808.5M TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    808.4M
```

Comment: If you're looking for alternatives for a slide-able control, try [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) with it's binding at [SWRevealViewController-Xamarin](https://github.com/Vandborg/SWRevealViewController-XamarinBinding) have been using that for a while without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a guess, but it looks like it's hitting a bug inside Xamarin.iOS where we don't generate the proper binding code for Objective-C blocks when those blocks can be null (this has already been filed as a bug [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17499#c1)).

If you had a complete test project I can run I'd be able to confirm this quickly.